# How to take full page screen shot in internet explorer using selenium webdrivers

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am not able to take the whole page screen shot using selenium webdriver.I am using internet explorer.
I tried robot function of java using mouse roll button but failed.

Comment: Hello and welcome to [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com). Please take some time to read
[the help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) is.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following let me know if it works for you

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.somewebsite.com/");
File imgFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(imgFile , new File("c:\\tmp\\test.png"));
```

if i have misunderstood you que please let me know

Answer (score 0):

If the above answer fails, you can give a try making using of Augemented WebDriver, which can be used with IEDriver on it's latest version, try following code

```
WebDriver augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);
File screenFile = ((TakesScreenshot) augmentedDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(screenFile.getAbsolutePath(), new File("c:\\tmp\\test.png"));
```

You can also get screenshot in the form of bytes, by switching the OutputType as required

```
.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES)
```